# Booting from usb fails as I try to install elementary OS on my PC

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, bios

I'm trying to install Elementary OS Luna on my PC. The problem is that every time I try to boot from my usb, on which I've got the OS installation files, it fails.

First I press <kbd>F12</kbd> to get to the Boot Manager, then I select the usb-hdd option and press enter. Then I see a black screen with some log messages and in the middle of the screen there's a message saying "KingstonDataTraveller (- this is the name of the USB I'm using) capability - disabled".

It looks like my BIOS can't open the files on the USB or I might have to change some other BIOS settings. This screen stays for a few seconds and then my Windows 7 load again.

Please help me I can't see what's wrong. I've created the bootable USB by using UNetbootin. This shouldn't be a problem, should it?

Answer (score 0):

When you go into your BIOS usually f2 or f10, go into configuration, USB legacy and enable that setting. That should enable the USB.