# Trying to install a Linux Distro (dual boot) from USB (Windows 10)

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, dual-boot, live-usb

I bought a 3.0 USB especially for the job but I'm about to give up for the day. I wanted to try basic Arch, then I tried makeiso, then antergos. I have 3 iso images all behaving the same way. Like this:

I use Rufus to make the iso image. It completes successfully ( I can see the files + autorun etc..). I then go to Window's Advanced Startup Options/Recovery and 'Restart'. When I get the option, I choose 'Boot from Other Device, USB etc..') Then on the next screen I pick my new sandisk stick.

Then it just starts as normal. I have tried loads of different ISOs and tried different permutations of options on Rufus. What should I check next?

Comment: iso images are for CDs, not USBs. You could try the Debian live ISO, it is a hybrid ISO/Usb image (so will work with both).

Comment: Rufus tells me to choose an  iso image. Are you sure about this? I thought the whole idea is that it behaves like a disk? #moreConfusedNow :)

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#Using_Rufus

Comment: It does but CD disks are different, they use ISO9660 file-system with El Torito boot loader extension, and juliet & rockridge extensions for long file-names and file attributes. This file-system came about because existing file-systems, for Microsoft OSs sucked, and it was infeasible to get Microsoft OSs to read Unix file-systems, as these had more that 11 character file-names. And so a new file-system was born, but only for CDs. Latter there was UDF (ISO/IEC 13346) for DVDs and blue-ray. But the short answer is that many computers can only boot ISO9660 from CD, and USBs as if a hard-disk.

Comment: From the text on the arch website that you link to, it seems as though their image is a hybrid as well. As they say it works on USB. If so then you need to look at your firmware-bootloader settings (often incorrectly called bios). see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115792/booting-from-usb-fails-as-i-try-to-install-elementary-os-on-my-pc?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the link kindly supplied by richard above in the comments.

unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115792/

Basically I had to do go into BIOS and disable 'Secure Boot', then enable 'Legacy Boot'. After this, the steps outlined in my question worked.

Thanks.